# Word Wrap - Break Word not working on my Accordion

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

My accordion headings aren't starting on a new line, despite using `word-wrap: break-word !important;` the text is currently going outside the card weirdly. This is making my page not suitable for mobile devices, I was just looking for some SO wisdom to see what I'm doing which is dumb here.

Thanks

```css
#accordion-style-1 h1,
#accordion-style-1 a {
    color: #0E112B;
    word-wrap: break-word !important;
}

#accordion-style-1 h5 .btn-link {
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #0E112B;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    font-size: 18px;
    word-wrap: break-word !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 25px;
    width:100% !important;
}

#accordion-style-1 .card-body {
    border-top: 2px solid #0E112B;
display:block;
}

#accordion-style-1 .card-header .btn.collapsed .fa.main {
    display: none;
}

#accordion-style-1 .card-header .btn .fa.main {
    background: #0E112B;
    padding: 13px 11px;
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 35px;
    height: 41px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -1px;
    top: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.1/css/all.css"
        integrity="sha384-O8whS3fhG2OnA5Kas0Y9l3cfpmYjapjI0E4theH4iuMD+pLhbf6JI0jIMfYcK3yZ"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
        

<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-between">
    <div class="col-md-6 my-auto col-12">
      <div class="col-12 mx-auto" id="accordion-style-1">
        <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
              <h5 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-link btn-block text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
         <i class="fa fa-calendar main"></i><i class="fas fa-angle-double-right mr-3"></i>How do I send an send reminders through pigs flying??
       </button>
              </h5>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show fade" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
              <div class="card-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
                on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
                raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
              <h5 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-link collapsed btn-block text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
        <i class="fa fa-plus main"></i><i class="fas fa-angle-double-right mr-3"></i>How do I send an send reminders through pigs flying??
       </button>
              </h5>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse fade" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
              <div class="card-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
                on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
                raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
              <h5 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-link collapsed btn-block text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
         <i class="fa fa-expeditedssl main"></i><i class="fas fa-angle-double-right mr-3"></i>How do I send an send reminders through pigs flying??
       </button>
              </h5>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse fade" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
              <div class="card-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
                on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
                raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="headingFour">
              <h5 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-link collapsed btn-block text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFour">
         <i class="fa fa-envelope main"></i><i class="fas fa-angle-double-right mr-3"></i>How do I send an send reminders through pigs flying??
       </button>
              </h5>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseFour" class="collapse fade" aria-labelledby="headingFour" data-parent="#accordionExample">
              <div class="card-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
                on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
                raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="headingFive">
              <h5 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-link collapsed btn-block text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFour">
         <i class="fa fa-envelope main"></i><i class="fas fa-angle-double-right mr-3"></i>How do I send an send reminders through pigs flying??
       </button>
              </h5>
            </div>
            <div id="Div2" class="collapse fade" aria-labelledby="headingFour" data-parent="#accordionExample">
              <div class="card-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
                on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
                raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" id="headingSix">
              <h5 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-link collapsed btn-block text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFour">
         <i class="fa fa-envelope main"></i><i class="fas fa-angle-double-right mr-3"></i>How do I send an send reminders through pigs flying??
       </button>
              </h5>
            </div>
            <div id="Div4" class="collapse fade" aria-labelledby="headingFour" data-parent="#accordionExample">
              <div class="card-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
                on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
                raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Apply *white-space: normal;*

Comment: To add to that, it's being inherited from your .btn class which sets: white-space: nowrap;

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks guys

Comment: Additionally, you should consider making the arrows the list bullet points so that the second line text is in line with the first line for that cleaner look.

Answer (score 7):

I think this will help you

```css
.accordion .card-header .btn-block{
 white-space:normal;
}
```

Comment: it's working, just using that line.. thanks :)